# Office Web Apps error with checkout required

Tags: check-out, office-web-apps

I have office web apps installed, everything works fine unless checkout is required on a document library, then I receive the error

> "An error occurred while opening this document.  To edit this document,
>   open it in Microsoft Word."

Is this default behaviour, or do I have some configuration issue perhaps?  SP and OWA are on SP1 and the June CU, using NTLM auth. The issue was also happening before the updates.